# Update SQL string format

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a database table column with values that look like "022417" and I'd like to construct a query that changes all of them to "02-24-2017", what would that query look like?

My initial attempt tried to use wildcard(?) syntax:

```
UPDATE b5_adproduct
SET ad_date = replace(ad_date, '______', '__-__-20__');
```

but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: If you're going through the effort of changing the data for the dates, why not change them to an actual `DATE` datatype?

Comment: So, if you have "022487" then what year would be from this? 1987, 2087 ...

Comment: actually migrating a Django CharField to a DateField but I have to change all of the existing values in the db to an acceptable format first.

Comment: using postgres but I though generic sql was what is needed.

Comment: 2087. The records in the db only stretch from last year. Hardcoding the 20 was a conscious choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated in a comment that your records only span from last year so this should work for all of them:

```
UPDATE `b5_adproduct` SET `ad_date` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`ad_date`, 1, 2), '-', SUBSTRING(`ad_date`, 3, 2), '-20', SUBSTRING(`ad_date`, 5, 2))
```

Also, make sure before that the field accepts more than 6 characters, just in case, since the string will get longer

Also, if you're planning to switch the field to a date field afterwards, the date will have to look like YYYY-MM-DD so you can use the following for that:

```
UPDATE `b5_adproduct` SET `ad_date` = CONCAT('20', SUBSTRING(`ad_date`, 5, 2), '-', SUBSTRING(`ad_date`, 1, 2), '-', SUBSTRING(`ad_date`, 3, 2))
```

Comment: I need something that will work for all of the 'ad_date' values on that table. That's why a wildcard strategy was my first thought.

Comment: I just tested it and it should work. Do you have dates with years before 2000?

Comment: This solution will work as long as the dates are not from another century like the great year 1999 or so...

Comment: Should have tested before I commented. Had to remove some quote marks but otherwise worked like a charm! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format()` with `substr()`, e.g.

```
update b5_adproduct
set ad_date = format(
    '%s-%s-20%s', 
    substr(ad_date, 1, 2), 
    substr(ad_date, 3, 2), 
    substr(ad_date, 5, 2))
returning *

 id |  ad_date   
----+------------
  1 | 02-24-2017
(1 row)
```

You can also alter type of the column converting the values at the same time, e.g.

```
alter table b5_adproduct 
    alter ad_date type date
    using make_date(
        substr(ad_date, 5, 2)::int+ 2000, 
        substr(ad_date, 1, 2)::int, 
        substr(ad_date, 3, 2)::int)
--  make_date(yyyy, mm, dd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to simply convert it into a date format. If you use MySQL it would be:

```
UPDATE `b5_adproduct` 
 SET `ad_date` = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`ad_date`, '%m%d%y'), '%m-%d-%Y');
```

Where `STR_TO_DATE()` converts your string to a date, and then use `DATE_FORMAT()` to specify the date format to display.

If you are using PostgreSQL you could use `to_date()` to convert your string to a date:

```
to_date('022417', 'MMDDYY')
```

Specifications: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this ( a bit different than the answer above - just replacing the declared variable with your own table value )

```
Declare @date nvarchar(10)
Set @date = '122417'

**select @date, substring(@date,1,2) + '-' + substring(@date,3,2) + '-20' + substring(@date,5,2)**

go
```

returns:

```
122417  12-24-2017
```

Comment: and just switching the select to a set date = substring... and the syntax to an update statement